# Find the inverse of a sequence in integers in Mathematica

Tags: dataset, wolfram-mathematica, sequences

Let `k[i]` is a strictly increasing data and

> A=Table[k[i],{i,1,30}];
>
> B=List[k[1],k[3],k[4],k[7],k[10],k[12],k[17],k[18],k[19],k[23],k[26]];

Now I would like to get what is the index for `B[n]`, for example `B[4]=A[7]`, and my question is to get `7`. I tried InverseFunction,

> InverseFunction[A][B[4]]

but it does  not work. A similar question arise when I define `A` and `B` by the following sets

> A=List[k[1],k[2],k[3],k[4],k[5],k[6],k[7],k[8],k[9],k[10],k[11],k[12],k[13],k[14],k[15]];
>
> B=List[k[1],k[3],k[4],k[7],k[10],k[12],k[14]];

If the problem is in the method of representing data by the function `List`, please let me know a better way.

Comment: Regarding the first, try `Position[A, B[[4]]][[1, 1]]`.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your question. Have your tried
B[[4, 1]]?

Comment: @b.gatessucks, thanks, it works. could you please help with this [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25863/find-a-sequence-of-integers-which-give-max-in-each-step][1]